# Can you create a 2D array with the new SwiftData macro?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I’ve been trying out SwiftData and I cannot seem to make a 2D Array. Is this a technical limitation of SwiftData? Or is there a work around?

When this code is run, and I press the button

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query var tests: [Test]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context

    var body: some View {
        Button("Add Test") {
            let newTest = Test()
            context.insert(newTest)
        }
    }
}
```

with this class

```
@Model class Test {
    var string2D = [[String]]()
    init() {}
}
```

I get the resulting error:

> Thread: 1 Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for Test

However, when I change the class to a normal array the code works fine.

```
@Model class Test {
    var strings = [String]()
    init() {}
}
```

I was able to work around this by creating a struct.

```
struct stringArray: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var strings: [String]

    init() {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.strings = []
    }
}
```

and change the class to:

```
@Model class Test {
    var string2D = [stringArray]()
    init() {}
}
```

However, this is messy and more complicated than I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Thinking about this some more I realised that this could work out of the box since we are supposed to be able to add properties of custom types as long as they conform to `Codable` and `[[String]]` clearly does that but then again will collections like array be considered custom types or do we need to use transformable for them?

The functionality with `Codable` doesn't work at all with the current beta of SwiftData (Xcode 15.0 beta 2) so for now this is an unknown.

---

*Original answer:*

The issue here is that you need to make your strings property a transformable property since arrays aren't supported by the underlying database. Also I believe none of your code actually worked, did you try to save anything to it and then reload the data? The bug for your second and third example is probably that SwiftData fails to generate a proper error. At lease that is what I saw when trying with a [String] as the property type, no error but no field for the array was created in the sql table.

Anyway, here is a simple attempt to use transformable in SwiftData that seems to work

Mark your attribute as transformable:

```
@Attribute(.transformable) var strings: [[String]]
```

and then create a transformer

```
@objc(String2DArrayValueTransformer)
final class String2DArrayValueTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {

    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: [[String]].self))
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [NSArray.self, NSArray.self]
    }

    public static func register() {
        let transformer = String2DArrayValueTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

With this solution I managed to insert and fetch data as expected. I got  warnings when fetching data about using `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` which I am not so I am not sure if that is my code or an issue with the beta version of SwiftData.

Comment: I have tried to avoid Transformable as much as possible when using Core Data so I am no expert, maybe someone else can spot an issue with my code regarding the warning. The full warning is _'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release_