# What is the purpose of the "transformable" option in the @Attribute macro?

Tags: swift, swift-data

The new SwiftData macro `@Attribute` provides a `.transformable` option. From the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/propertyoptions/transformable):

> Transforms the property’s value between an in-memory form and a persisted form.

This description is rather unclear. What is the purpose of this option and when is it necessary to use it?

Comment: You can use it if you want to store data of a type that isn’t supported by SwiftData. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76596423/9223839) or look up the documentation for Core Data Transformable, it probably has more information

Comment: `SwiftData` is based on `CoreData`. See for instance https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data In a nutshell it serves as saving `Data` (a type that can be saved into CoreData) a "irregular" type. Ie CustomType <-> Data.